# create a list stream from a map stream

Tags: dart, stream

I have a project that requires me to work with streams.

I have a Stream of a Map with the following code:

```
Stream<Map<String,TextBlock>> get phoneNumberBlocks =>
      visionMatch.map((MatchVisionTextRegex ourRegexDetection) {
        final Map<String,TextBlock> list = <String,TextBlock>{};
        for (MatchVisionTextData textData in ourRegexDetection.phone) {
          list[textData.parsedText]=textData.textBlock;
        }
        return list;
      }).asBroadcastStream();
```

now I want to create another stream that takes the `phoneNumberBlocks` stream of map, and returns another stream of a list of the keys of that map.

so far I have this:

```
Stream<List<String>> get phoneNumbers =>
      phoneNumberBlocks.map<String,TextBlock>((String s, TextBlock b) =>
      s).asBroadcastStream();
```

which is totally broken and doesn't work! :) any ideas how to achieve this ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StreamTransformer` since its purpose it is to receive a stream, transform it and return a new one.

So given a `Stream` of `Map<String,String>`:

```dart
StreamController<Map<String,String>> streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
Stream<Map<String,String>> get phoneNumberBlocks => streamController.stream;
```

You can create a new one like this:

```dart
Stream<List<String>> get phoneNumbers => phoneNumberBlocks.transform(StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
  handleData: (Map<String,String> data, sink) {
    sink.add(data.keys.toList());
  }
));
```

The `StreamTransformer` will receive the data from `phoneNumberBlocks` and add only the `keys` from the map into the new `Stream` of `List<String>`.

A practical example:

```dart
void main() {
  phoneNumbers.listen((s) => print(s));

  streamController.sink.add({
    '1': 'a',
    '2': 'b',
    '3': 'c',
  });
}
```

Console:

> [1, 2, 3]

See it in action [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b1a081b7dbc0b4819189d37f65582c82).

Comment: man you should get a reward for the best answer possible! code examples, code description, practical example, running code on dart pad. you helped me a lot! thank you so much!